# Does "hook_ENTITY_TYPE_load" have performance advantages over "hook_entity_load"?

Tags: 8, entities

I googled *Drupal 8 `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_load` faster than `hook_entity_load`*, but got no information on the question.

I was told that putting an entity type in the hook name is faster than putting an `if` statement for the entity type inside `hook_entity_load()`. This makes sense to me, but I want to make sure.

I also have a subscription to drupalize.me and couldn't find anything that supports the possibility of `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_load()` being faster than `hook_entity_load()`. In fact, it tells me to use `hook_entity_storage_load()` for that purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference in the overhead. The only difference is that one is called earlier than the other. I can't remember which off the top of my head though.

Answer (score 4):

The only difference is that `hook_entity_load()` is invoked for every entity loaded, while `hook_ENTITY_TPE_load()` is invoked for every entity for which the entity type is *ENTITY_TYPE*.
If a module implemented `hook_entity_load()` only to handle a specific entity type, or a group of entity types, but not every entity type, its `hook_entity_load()` implementation would need to check which entity is being loaded, but since the second argument passed to the hook (`$entity_type_id`) is the entity type, checking that isn't time consuming nor a performance issue.

As for using `hook_entity_load()` or `hook_entity_storage_load()`, the second hook is invoked for content entities (not configuration entities) with a storage handler that saves the data in the database. In the other cases, including entities loaded from the entity cache, only `hook_entity_load()` is invoked.

Comment: I was perusing drupalize.me some more and it said that hook_ENTITY_TYPE_create was slightly more performant than hook_entity_create. Wouldn't this be true for hook_entity_load and hook_ENTITY_TYPE_load?

Comment: No. Even if the modules would implement `hook_entity_load()` and check the entity type created, the difference would be minimal, if it's notable.